# Split stereo channels over two simultaneous usb audio devices

Tags: audio, windows-7, usb

I can't seem to find a question that clearly asks or received a solid answer for this. I have two Dell USB sound bars. I want to play left channel audio over one and right channel audio over the other. Because they are USB, I don't believe I need a sound card(s) to achieve this, just a program or driver that would perform this function, unless the sound card had that built into the driver. I don't need any frills, just to split audio channels between devices that play simultaneously from a Windows 7 OS. Virtual Audio Cable was suggested by some, but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this feat.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ASIO drivers, this will split each of the drivers up individually. I know from music production you would be able to achieve what you want, but if it is for general audio I couldn't possibly say [Asio Website here](http://www.asio4all.com/) Do you want it on all audio or are you doing this for production?

Edit:

[Image of ASIO drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoNik.png) 
Hope this helps!

Sam